# Quick form validation

Tags: php, pear, quickform

I use db dataobject, and thus quickform. I got stuck with a problem. want to set a validation at the client side to check a file name extension. Can't find a way out.

the field is like:

```
'pathname' => array(
'type' => 'varchar',
'size' =>255,
'qf_type'=> 'text',
'require' => false,
'qf_client' => true,
'qf_rules' = array('required' => 'file name is required.'),
);
```

now I want a validation to check whether the extension of the file matches with some specific format with the help of regular expression.
If any one has idea please share.

Comment: IIRC this often is not possible client-side because many browsers don't give you the filename of the upload field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved setting pathname['qf_rules']['regex'].